# "The URL _catalogs/fpdatasources is invalid" in SharePoint designer when publishing a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, error-handling

When I try and publish a workflow I get the following error.

[image]

I have tried creating a fresh workflow in this list and other lists. this is apparently a sitewide problem. The only references I can find online to this problem are for on-premise SharePoint environments and suggest a full logging database but I'm on O365.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've found the answer. 
If you encounter this sort of error on a on-prem SharePoint environment it's a symptom of a full logging DB but, obviously, SharePoint Online doesn't have that facility. What it does have is a local web cache. This is a SharePoint designer caching issue and here is the fix:

1. Open File > Options > Application Options: and uncheck "Cache site data across SharePoint Designer Sessions"
2. Close SharePoint Designer 2013
3. Open Users > {current user} > AppData > Local > Microsoft > and Delete the folder "WebsiteCache"

Now re-open your site and everything should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this issue occurs on other site collections in your tenant. If it also happens on other site collections, you need to contact Office 365 support via Office 365 Admin Center->Support->"new service request" to check if there is something wrong in the back-end.